# Java random selection of lines in csv file for output

Tags: file-io, random

I want to read in a variable length csv file and randomly select a percentage of lines from the file to be output. For instance if I have 20 lines I would read each line in counting up to 20 the last line will have a number only (the percentage). then figure this percentage from the number of lines read in for instance 10 on the last line would give me 20 * 10% so 2 lines to be randomly picked and output to a text file. any ideas? how would i verify that it is indeed random?

Comment: It won't be random, it'll be pseudo-random, but that's probably good enough. /pedantry

Answer (score 1):

1. Insert the lines into a `String[]`
2. Calculate the number of lines you want to select: `int number = (int)(myArray.length * percentage);`
3. Pick a [random sample](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/random_sample.shtml) from the `String[]`

Comment: Don't forget to leave the last line out of the string array.